# react-native import component from another component

Tags: android, react-native

i have project in react-native and its ok , my problem is when i tried to import component in another component its failed but when import at index.android.js its ok why ??

index.android.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ToastAndroid,
  ListView,
  Navigator,
} from 'react-native';


import LoginView from './App/LoginView';
```

its ok but when tried to import the same in another screen like this

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';  
    import {  
        StyleSheet,
        ToolbarAndroid
        ,AppRegistry,
        View,
        Text,
        TouchableHighlight,
        TextInput,
        ListView,ActionButton,
        Image
    } from 'react-native';
    import LoginView from './App/LoginView';

    export default class MyOrders extends Component 

{
```

i got this error , "Ruquring unknown module if you are sure the module is there try to restarting the packeger or running npm install" ????

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause may be relative path('./App/LoginView') could be wrong with respect to the component while importing.Try updating the relative path accordingly.After updating stop the react-native dev server and again start it using `react-native start`.

Comment: thank you , but i used same statement in index.android.js its running and in another its not !!

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your directory structure

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider that you are importing AboutUs page in index.ios.js 
by using the following
var AboutUs = require('./Views/AboutUs');

AboutUs.js is located in "Views" directory which is located in place where index.ios.js page located. And in AboutUs.js page you have to export the component by
module.exports = AboutUs;
Where,

class AboutUs extends Component {
  .....
}

Comment: ok if your answer is right ! why in index.android.js ok ! and in another no ?

Comment: I didnt get ur comment @Bokerjy Zahgan.

Comment: if my answer worked for you please up vote. thanks in advance :)